# Can't install opencv from source

Tags: c++, opencv

It's OpenCV-2.4.0

```
cd opencv
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
make
```

Error:

```
In file included from OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp:460:
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:35:1: warning: missing terminating " character
In file included from OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp:460:
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:35: error: missing terminating " character
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:36:11: error: too many decimal points in number
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:36:29: error: invalid suffix "st" on integer constant
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:40:29: warning: character constant too long for its type
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:57: error: stray ‘@’ in program
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:57: error: stray ‘@’ in program
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:68:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:71: error: stray ‘\’ in program
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:71:9: warning: missing terminating " character
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:71: error: missing terminating " character
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:74:23: warning: missing terminating " character
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:1515: error: stray ‘\’ in program
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:1515:4: warning: missing terminating " character
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:1515: error: missing terminating " character
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc: In function ‘const std::string& cv::getBuildInformation()’:
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:36: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘version’
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:138: error: ‘z_stream’ was not declared in this scope
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:140: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘typedef’
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:161: error: ‘gz_header’ was not declared in this scope
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:163: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘typedef’
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:1505: error: ‘ZEXTERN’ was not declared in this scope
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:1505: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘const’
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:1511: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc: At global scope:
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:1515: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp:462: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp:465: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp:474: error: ‘string’ does not name a type
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp:503: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Exception’ with no type
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp:503: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp: In function ‘void error(int)’:
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp:506: error: ‘exc’ was not declared in this scope
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp:510: error: ‘exc’ was not declared in this scope
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp:526: error: ‘exc’ was not declared in this scope
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp: At global scope:
OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/system.cpp:543: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What should i do?

Comment: Write a bug report. http://code.opencv.org/

Comment: @ypnos, please don't encourage bogus bug reports.

Comment: @Shambool, this is not bogus. OpenCV2.4.0 fails to build on Debian 6.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having the same problem building OpenCV-2.4.0 on Debian 6.0.  Looking at `release/modules/core/version_string.inc` showed the missing `"` also a missing comment `/*`, which occurred in `using zlib v1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3`.  I reconfigured with `BUILD_ZLIB` and had no problems.

Comment: Build fails because of CMake 2.8.2 bug. See http://code.opencv.org/issues/1902 for details.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I changed the CMakeLists.txt file by replacing the line:

```
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_ZLIB               "Build zlib from source"         WIN32 OR IOS OR APPLE )
```

with:

```
OCV_OPTION(BUILD_ZLIB       "Build zlib from source"   ON) #  WIN32 OR IOS OR APPLE )
```

and everything got fine.

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded OpenCV 2.4.0 sources from the repository (rev 8300) and I had no problems building it on Linux:

```
$ svn info
Path: .
URL: http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/tags/2.4.0/opencv
Repository Root: http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv
Repository UUID: c5418bc3-7546-4aae-8bad-fa6f2f3e53e6
Revision: 8300
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: marina.kolpakova
Last Changed Rev: 8282
Last Changed Date: 2012-04-30 16:06:37 -0300 (Mon, 30 Apr 2012)

$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
$ make
```

**20 minutes later it was over and successfully compiled.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems the error comes from cmake 2.8.2. I upgraded to version 2.8.8 and finally I could install opencv 2.4.0.