# Compile OpenCV 2.4.2 for Debian Lenny

Tags: unix, opencv, cmake

**To keep the Q&A aspect:**

I got a strange problem with the latest (v.2.4.2) OpenCV version, which failed to install with the following error:

> In file included from /OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/system.cpp:460:
>   /OpenCV-2.4.2/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:37:1:
>   warning: missing terminating " character In file included from
>   /OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/system.cpp:460:
>   /OpenCV-2.4.2/release/modules/core/version_string.inc:37: error:
>   missing terminating " character

So what went wrong? *Take a look at my answer.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't install opencv from source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429570/cant-install-opencv-from-source)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in [this bug report](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2006) the problem is an old version (2.8.2) of cmake. So the solution was to grab a fresh copy of the cmake source, compile it and use it to install OpenCV.

**Note 18/09/2012:** This also works on Ubuntu 12.04 with cmake 2.8.9!

```
# get the cmake src
wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.8.tar.gz

# extract archive
tar xfvz cmake-2.8.8.tar.gz

# build the new version
cd cmake-2.8.8
cmake . 
make 
sudo make install

# get the OpenCV src
wget -O OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.bz2 http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.2/OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.bz2/download

# extract it …
tar -xvf OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.bz2

# build it
mkdir build
cd build
/usr/local/bin/cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ..
make
sudo make install

# setup OpenCV
sudo echo “/usr/local/lib” >> /etc/ld.so.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

That's it.

Comment: +1 I've seen some questions complaining about this sort of problems. Never crossed my mind to update CMake. Good work!

Comment: What if i need to create the SO files of the library?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately newer cmake depends on newer cmake than the outdated cmake 2.6-patch 0 in lenny. To compile cmake 2.8.8 as mentioned above, first you have to compile CMake 2.6.3 or above which builds with lenny outdated cmake 2.6-patch 0.